# Javascript Resize Image not working

Tags: javascript

I have JS which resize the `width` and `height` of Image which is working fine if I used Alert before assigning the actual image src to the image object and if I omit the alertbox, it is not working. Please suggest me how to fix it.

`

```
<html>
        <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function resize_image_height_weight(id, hgt, wdth)
        {
            //alert(id);
            Obj=document.getElementById(id);
            myImage = new Image();
            myImage.src = Obj.src;
            var heights = myImage.height;
            var widths  = myImage.width;
        //  alert("Height=>" + heights + " Width=> " + widths);

            if(heights > hgt || widths > wdth)
            {
                if(heights > widths)
                {
                    var temp = heights/hgt;
                    var new_width = widths / temp;
                    new_width = parseInt(new_width);
                    heights = hgt;
                    widths = new_width;
                }
                else
                {
                    var temp = widths/wdth;
                    var new_height = heights / temp;
                    new_height = parseInt(new_height);
                    heights = new_height;
                    widths = wdth;
                }
            }
            Obj.height = heights;
            Obj.width = widths;

        }
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>
            <center>
            <img src="http://www.google.co.in/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png" id="i" alt="Google logo" height="150" width="150">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                document.images[document.images.length-1].onload = resize_image_height_weight("i",150,150);
            </script>
            </center>
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function assigned to onload:

```
> document.images[document.images.length-1].onload =
> resize_image_height_weight("i",150,150);
```

you are assigning the result of calling `resize_image_height_weight` which throws an error in IE. Set it to a function instead:

```
document.images[document.images.length-1].onload = function() {
          resize_image_height_weight("i",150,150);
};
```

Comment: Could you help me more. Now I am doing one step more. I am write the code using javascript(using InnerHTML Method) on scroll of mouse to display more images while user scroll the page. But now the function resize_image_height_weight is not called.

Answer (score 1):

When you set the .src on an image, you have to wait until the image is successfully loaded until you can read it's height and width.  There is an onload event handler that will tell you when the image is loaded.

Here's a place in your code where this issue could occur:

```
        Obj=document.getElementById(id);
        myImage = new Image();
        myImage.src = Obj.src;
        var heights = myImage.height;
        var widths  = myImage.width;
```

In this case, since the image was already elsewhere in the document, you should just read the height and width off the existing element rather than the new element.

Be very careful when testing because if the image is in your browser cache, it may load immediately, but when it's not in your cache, it takes some time to load and won't be available immediately.

Putting an alert at the right place in your script can allow the image to load before the script proceeds which could explain why it works with the alert.

As RobG mentions, your onload handler is also faulty (needs to be a function, not the returned result of a function).

Here's a simpler function to scale an image to fit the bounds.  This uses a trick that you only need to set one size (height or width on the image) and the other will be scaled by the browser to preserve the aspect ratio.

```
function resizeImage(id, maxHeight, maxWidth) {
    // assumes the image is already loaded
    // assume no height and width is being forced on it yet
    var img = document.getElementById(id);
    var height = img.height || 0;
    var width = img.width || 0;
    if (height > maxHeight || width > maxWidth) {
        var aspect = height / width;
        var maxAspect = maxHeight / maxWidth;
        if (aspect > maxAspect) {
            img.style.height = maxHeight + "px";
        } else {
            img.style.width = maxWidth + "px";
        }
    }
}
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/BeJg4/.

Comment: The OP is calling the fuction using image.onload. Note that until HTML5, there was no standard onload attribute for img elements.

Comment: I've added a specific reference to code where there is no onload handler and the height may not be valid when it's being read.  Also, standard or not, the event for images being loaded is widely supported, widely useful and widely used.

Comment: Hi there,

Thanks for your response. So could you suggest me is there any way to fix it without using alert box? My motive is to resize the image if the height or width of image is greater than 150.

Comment: I've added to my answer a resizeImage routine that works a lot more simply.

Comment: Thx jfriend00 for your kind help.